# Define custom classifier for glue crawler

Tags: amazon-web-services, jsonpath, aws-glue

I am trying to define a custom jsonpath classifier for my glue crawler.  I am trying to crawl json files of the following structure

```
{
   "orders" : [{
     "key1": "val1",
     "key2": "val3"
   },
   {
     "key1": "val1",
     "key2": "val3"
   }]
}
```

What would the appropriate jsonpath pattern be to define the classifier to pickup the array items as individual records by the glue crawler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the individual array elements with `$.orders[n]`, where `n` is your counter.